# Hibernate query does return zero record while same query on mysql returns records

Tags: hibernate

The following query in MySQL fetched the 10 records:

`select orderID from VOrders limit 10210, 10`

while equivalent to the above sql query in the Hibernate returns empty list, using the following code:

```
 Query query = session.createQuery("select orderID from VOrders");
    query.setFirstResult(new Integer(10210));
    query.setMaxResults(new Integer(10));
    session.close();
    return query.list();
```

Please help

Comment: Why do you close the session before executing the query ?

Comment: Sorry, this line is accidently added. It is not in actual code.

Comment: Turn on Hibernate's SQL logging and see how exactly the generated query differs from the one that works.

Comment: Thanks @PredragMaric. I found the issue in the code after analyzing the printed query. The SQL query has a 'group by' clause so mismatching the total records count and fetched records

Comment: Great, glad you found the issue.